# How many ports does an AWS EC2 machine have?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to run a Docker container on my EC2 machine. The container is an API for a game lobby service, and it listens to port 4242 by default.

When I try to send an HTTP request in the browser, I don't get anything. Does the EC2 even have a port 4242?

My apologies if this question is too vague. I am very new to this whole networking thing.

Answer (score 5):

An EC2 instance is a Windows or Linux computer. It has *all* the TCP ports, from 0 to 65535, just like any other computer.

You may need to open the port in any firewall software running on the server, and you will definitely need to open the port in the AWS Security Group assigned to the EC2 instance.